# AFNetworking + cocoapods + user session expiration monitoring

Tags: ios, objective-c, cookies, afnetworking

I have a client-server application that has a server singleton in it that is a subclass of `AFHTTPSessionManager` which was installed using cocoapods. When user is logging in they have their session cookie stored and they can perform different actions that require active session without providing their credentials more than once while the session is active. I have something around 50+ server calls that require user to be authenticated and which can return a JSON response stating that user's session is no longer valid and needs to be refreshed - by this event I should drop user out to login screen and ask them to re-login. I know that there's a method somewhere in the AFNetworking core that's processing raw responses for all the GET and POST methods before turning them into a `responseObject` of the `id` type but I cannot use it since I'm using cocoapods and can't really modify the core of a pod (I'm using git and pods aren't included in the commits). The question is - how do I handle user session expiration event centralized, not repeating it throughout 50+ different method calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way or not, but I have solved this by creating a unified method to parsing error responses from server and put the check on whether user is authenticated or not into it like below and post an NSNotification I post when user logs out via logout button in app:

```
// in context of creating a request
success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
            NSString *errors = [self errors:responseObject[@"errors"]];
           }

- (NSString *)errors:(id)errors
{
  NSString *errMsg = nil;
  if ([errors isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    errMsg = @"";
    for (NSString *key in errors) {
      errMsg = [errMsg stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@: ", key];
      errMsg = [errMsg stringByAppendingString:[[errors objectForKey:key] componentsJoinedByString:@" "]];
      errMsg = [errMsg stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
    }
  }
  else if ([errors isKindOfClass:[NSError class]]) {
    if (!self.reachabilityManager.reachable) {
      errMsg = @"Host isn't reachable. Please make sure you have an active Internet connection and try again later.";
    }
    else {
      errMsg = [errors localizedDescription];
    }
  }
  else if ([errors isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    if ([errors isEqualToString:@"Operation requires authorized access."]) {
      [CPAlertManager showMessage:@"Please re-authenticate." withTitle:@"Session expired."];
      [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CPUserLoginStatusChanged
                                                          object:@{ @"CPUserLoginStatus" : @(CPUserLoginStatusLoggedOut) }];
    }
    else {
      errMsg = errors;
    }
  }
  return errMsg;
}
```